# Bash script putting input without input redirection for a c++ file

Tags: bash

This is what I have"

```
#!/bin/bash
MAX=3

for((ctr = 0;ctr < MAX; ++ctr))
do
    ./make.o  > out$ctr.txt
    output$ctr.txt 
done
```

so I want to take put the output of make.o into out$ctr.txt and in my make.o I call cin, could I take output$ctr.txt as input? I would rather not use input redirection since I would have to rewrite the program.

EDIT: I do not want to use < because then it will give me the contents of the file output$ctr.txt, I do want the actual name of the file not the contents

Answer (score 0, accepted):

But what you actually want is:

```
./make.o output$ctr.txt >out$ctr.txt
```

where `output$ctr.txt` is a *command-line argument* to your program.

Assuming a C++ program, since you mention `cin`, you handle command-line arguments like this:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc < 2) {
        // argv[0] usually contains the program name
        std::cerr << "missing argument\n"
                  << "Syntax: " << argv[0] << " input-file\n";
        return -1;
    }

    char *input = argv[1]; // = "output$ctr.txt"
    // ...
}
```

---

### First Guess

It sounds like you just want;

```
./make.o  >out$ctr.txt <output$ctr.txt
```

`>` redirects the file descriptor STDOUT_FILENO which is associated with `FILE *stdout` and `std::cout`.

`<` redirects the file descriptor STDIN_FILENO which is associated with `FILE *stdin` and `std::cin`.

Comment: No I do not want to use < because I do not want to read in the file I simply want to get the name of the file.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean like this

```
./make.o < output$ctr.txt  > out$ctr.txt
```

Edit: if you want the name, then just do this:

```
./make.o output$ctr.txt  > out$ctr.txt
```

or maybe this, to `echo` the name so it can be read from C++ `cin`:

```
echo output$ctr.txt | ./make.o  > out$ctr.txt
```

Comment: I do not want to use input redirection because I do not want to get the context for output$ctr.txt I just want the actual name output$ctr.txt

Comment: Edited answer, is either of new versions what you want, then?

Answer (score 0):

Just a comment about you loop, another more simpler way to write it is

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in {0..2}
do
    echo $i
done
```